# Gitlab was unable to access your Gitolite system

Tags: github, gitolite, gitlab

I installed GitLab on Ubuntu server 12.
I followed this steps:  http://blog.compunet.co.za/gitlab-installation-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/

Everything seems to be right... but when I try to create a new project, I get the error message:

```
Gitlab was unable to access your Gitolite system.
```

I ran the diagnostic tool ("`bundle exec rake gitlab:app:status RAILS_ENV=production`")

```
(in /home/gitlab/gitlab) Starting diagnostic
config/database.yml.............exists
config/gitlab.yml.............exists
/home/git/repositories/...........exists 
/home/git/repositories/ is writable?........YES 
remote: Counting objects: 12, done. 
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done. 
Receiving objects: 100% (12/12), 1.12KiB, done. 
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done. 
remote:Total 12 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0) 
Can clone gitolite-admin?..............YES 
UMASK for .gitolite.rc is 0007?............YES
 /home/git/share/gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive exists?............YES
```

Finished

The log on admin area only shows:

> ERROR -> /home/gitlab/gitlab/tmp/gitlabhq-gitolite-1348050652/gitolite

The `config/gitlab.yml` file is ok.
The permissions on repositories are just like the tutorial  (section 3 - permissions).
I even tried to remove the lock...

What would you advise to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is it possible you have some read/write right issues on  `/home/gitlab/gitlab/tmp/`?

Comment: just tried to change `/home/gitlab/gitlab/tmp/` permissions... still not working...

Comment: a found a possible fix... about gitolite permissions on:
`https://github.com/wingrunr21/gitolite/commit/cb100415e7`

sorry to ask (its kind of newbie).. but how do I apply this patch ?

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, I had a very similar situation happen, except in my gitlab log I had the following error:

> ERROR -> Pull error -> unable to clone gitolite-admin repo

I had compared the commit of the [gitolite fork](https://github.com/wingrunr21/gitolite/commit/cb100415e7) metioned, and found that the changes there were already in place in my version of gitlab.

I ended up stopping the gitlab related services, deleting the contents of the gitlab *tmp* directory, then restarted the gitlab related services.

Afterwards, everything appeared to be working fine.

Comment: unfortunately I'm having the same problem ant this solution didn't fix it :/

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure that all of the services of gitlab are stopped before you delete the content of your tmp folder and restart the service.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue comes from permission regex fixed in this [commit of this gitolite fork](https://github.com/wingrunr21/gitolite/commit/cb100415e7), you can have a look at "[GitHub Tip: download commits as patches](http://chem-bla-ics.blogspot.fr/2011/01/github-tip-download-commits-as-patches.html)":

Your commit can be downloaded by adding a `.patch` at the end of its url: **[patch](https://github.com/wingrunr21/gitolite/commit/cb100415e7.patch)**.

That way, you can apply it to your current gitolite source (without even using git itself, just by using the [`patch` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29))

Comment: I think that is exacly what I need.
i tried:
`curl https://github.com/wingrunr21/gitolite/commit/cb100415e7.patch  /tmp/fix.patch`

and then:
`git apply /tmp/fix.patch`

i got this:
`error: patch failed: Gemfile.lock:1
error: Gemfile.lock: patch does not apply
error: lib/gitolite/config/repo.rb: File not found
error: spec/repo_spec.rb: File not found

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue on my server by following the installation instructions section titled "Disable StrictHostKeyChecking for localhost and your domain" and adding a new section for my gitolite host, which was set to the IP address of the server rather than localhost. Open:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

And add the lines:

```
Host [gitolite hostname/IP here]
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

(replace the bracketed part with the appropriate hostname/IP)

It's already in the setup steps, but I had skipped it earlier because I didn't understand what it was suggesting. Otherwise, the SSH client tries to show the yes/no prompt to accept a new hostname and the Ruby backend interprets that as a failure to connect to gitolite.